# Firefox extension development - reference to extension path

Tags: firefox-addon

I develop a firefox extension for configuration printer automatically. I want to create a configuration file at where extension was installed. can anybody help me?

Comment: This is the seventh question you've asked on stack overflow and none of them have been accepted yet, even though there are plenty of answers.  You might want to go and fix that or people may not want to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not actually want to store it where your add-on is installed because if you ever need to update the add-on, the configuration file will be overwritten.  What you really want to do is to place the configuration file in the [profile directory](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=en/File_I%2F%2FO#Getting_special_files) or in a folder you create inside the profile directory.